# Different programs, different resolutions?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, unity3d

As in the screenshot below Unity looks fuzzy, while file explorer is nice and crisp

[image: screenshot]

The fuzzy unity thing is happening with other programs too.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's happening because of Windows 10's DPI virtualization. That feature makes sure UI elements are big enough to be readable at high resolutions, but it also introduces blurriness. Since Windows Explorer has support for high DPI, Windows doesn't need to do any simple bitmap streching. Unity, however, apparently isn't DPI-aware.

To disable display scaling for a program (Unity, for instance), open its shortcut's properties, open the Compatibility tab, and check *Disable display scaling on high DPI settings*.

You might also try playing around with the system-wide DPI settings; <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `dpiscaling` will launch the *Change the size of all items* Control Panel applet.

Further reading: [KB2900023](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2900023)